# Cannot log back into desktop environment after running "setxkbmap il" and logging out

Tags: kde, opensuse, xkb, kde5

On OpenSUSE Leap 42.3, with KDE desktop environment, I changed the X11 keyboard map by running `$ setxkbmap il` to type something on LibreOffice Writer with a local language. Then after a period of inactivity my desktop environment got locked automatically. Now, I'm not able to login to desktop environment because my keyboard layout is still set to `il` but my username and password are in `us`. What should I do?

Comment: alt-ctr-f2, kill screenlocker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To fix it:**

Switch to a console (as suggested in the comment): <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F2</kbd>, login, and then:

- kill the screenlock program (with `htop`, `kill lockprogramname` etc), or
- restart the display manager (`systemctl restart display-manager.service`), or
- try to run `setxkbmap` (`env DISPLAY=:0 setxkbmap us`), or
- reboot the system

---

**To avoid it in the future:**

Use multiple layouts in your `setxkbmap` command and set a **group toggle** key to switch between the layouts.  You can load up to 4 independent layouts this way.  See `man xkeyboard-config` for various `grp:` options.

```
$ setxkbmap -layout us,il -option grp:shift_caps_toggle

# grp:shift_caps_toggle    Shift+CapsLock
# grp:ctrls_toggle         Both Ctrl together
# grp:alt_caps_toggle      Alt+CapsLock
# grp:sclk_toggle          Scroll Lock
```

Comment: It worked! From now on, I run `$ setxkbmap -layout us,il -option grp:shift_caps_toggle` and when I log out and want to log back, I have the option to change the keyboard layout